# why methods of Hashtable class are synchronized

Tags: java, hashtable, synchronized

By default , web app containers treat/create a separate thread for each request . In this context

1. How web app container creates a thread for each request.
2. Lets say T1 and T2 are requests/threads running more or less at the same time, and below statment will create a new object for each thread/request.
   Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
   i.e each thread will get its own instance of hashtable.

   t1 --> will get an instance/memory for hashtable

   t2 --> will get an instance/memory for hashtable

   As, both the threads are not sharing ...not sure why hashtable methods needs to be synchronized.

Comment: It's an over-synchronized legacy class. Use a `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`.

Comment: Hashtable is basically obsolete since Java 1.2, 19 years ago. Don't use Hashtable. Its javadoc says: *As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable.*.

Comment: "not sure why hashtable methods needs to be synchronized." Are you asking about why they are synchronized on the hashtable class, or about why *your* code accesses them in synchronized methods?

Comment: My question is " why methods in Hashtable class are synchronized"  . When each thread/request to an web application get its own copy of hashtable (new Hashtable()) .. I see that there is no need for synchronization of Hashtable methods.

Comment: Just because they are synchronized does not mean they need to be synchronized in your specific case. They are synchronized because the developers decided to make Hashtable thread-safe.

Comment: The answer is that they didn't know any better when they wrote Hashtable.

Comment: Im not synchronizing explicity..Im just trying to understand why Java community decided to make methods of this class synchronized.  Whatever reason we give to justify synchronziation of this class , would that not applicable for all the methods of all rest of Java API) ....Here., I just took a scenario to understand innerworkings of hashtable...And to put in other words....hashtable is not a singleton object....then what is the need for synchronized methods,as each thread that encounters (new hashtable()) will create a new instance.

Comment: In your case there is no need. However, what keeps you from sharing the Hashtable between threads? This is why in JDK1.0 the developers decided to make Vector and Hashtable thread-safe. They choose safety over performance. Later, in JDK1.2 they decided not to do the same for the new collection classes, as the synchronization was often not needed (like in your case), causing unnecessary performance overhead. Basically, the synchronization of Hashtable was a bad decision, which was corrected in JDK1.2 with HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

`Hashtable` is a very old class that was there since Java 1.0. While it's not officially `@Deprecated`, it's considered outdated, and you should probably be using a `HashMap` instead. Or, as the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) eloquently put it:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.

Comment: I understand the concept ...But Im trying to understand in the context of question asked.